# Explicit bounds for exceptional zeros and/or $L(1,\chi)$ for real $\chi$

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, l-functions

I would like to have an explicit upper bound (that is, one with explicit constants) for a possible real zero $\beta$ for $L(1,\chi)$ for real Dirichlet characters $\chi$. I need such a bound for real characters $\chi$ to any modulus, not just prime modulus. ([Ford/Luca/Moree, lemma 3](http://arxiv.org/abs/1108.3805) provides such a bound when the modulus is prime, of the form
$$
\beta \le 1 - \frac{25\pi}{4\sqrt q\log^2q}
$$
when $q$ is a large prime; I expect that the general result I'm seeking would be of similar quality.)

Essentially equivalently, I would like a lower bound for $|L(1,\chi)|$ for such characters $\chi$. (The proof of Ford/Luca/Moree proceeds in this way, and bounds $|L(1,\chi)|$ using Dirichlet's class number formula.)

I would be happy with either an argument laid out here (the more complete, the better) or a reference to the literature.

Comment: The (standard) argument in Ford/Luca/Moree doesn't really use that $q$ is prime, and works for any fundamental discriminant.

Comment: I see, so ... that would be enough to deal with all primitive real characters, and then one would just use the Euler product to deal with imprimitive characters?

Comment: Yes; the results should only get better for imprimitive characters.  Also the $\log^2$ in the denominator can be removed while still using only the trivial bound for the class number (but maybe no one wrote up an explicit version of that -- maybe useful to do if you're really fighting for constants) -- see Goldfeld and Schinzel http://archive.numdam.org/ARCHIVE/ASNSP/ASNSP_1975_4_2_4/ASNSP_1975_4_2_4_571_0/ASNSP_1975_4_2_4_571_0.pdf